# Codeigniter:Why use MVC approach instead of using only view and controller

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

Basically question is not about `Codeigniter` but about MVC architecture.

When I joined company my senior told me to use `controller` and `views` only its sufficient.Since I was new to Codeigniter, i did as he said.
Now i understand that company is small scale, it requires fast projects development.
But now he has gone, I want to learn MVC architecture, I have basic question whats the benefit of using MVC instead of using only view and controller.

FYI: My senior did know about MVC, but he just didn't pass on.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105352/why-should-i-use-an-mvc-pattern and  a short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vfmr0iXyYVA

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a great structure helping programmer to make large code without much messing up. It can be upgraded in the future by other programmers. It can be more secure as you don't use same code again and again by help of models.

When you learn MVC then you can learn faster how to use frameworks. Yeah controller view structure is a good point to start but you'll love mvc when you learn it and see it can help you a lot in speed.